# Is there a difference between tomo and tomodachi?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I was able to translate the terms as friend. Is there any difference in meaning between the 2 terms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

友｛とも｝ 'tomo' is basically not used in everyday modern Japanese. You may sometimes encounter it in literary writing, or in fiction to make a character sound archaic. 友達｛ともだち｝ 'tomodachi' is the ordinary casual word for 'friend'. You can use it in most situations, though formally you can also say 友人{ゆうじん｝ 'yuujin'.